# Groupby integer ID, python messed up with the integer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want a pandas dataframe to group by a column named 'ad_id', each entry in this column is an integer, for example, 7, 12, 120003, 12, 7. When I groupby, python seems messed up with the integer, instead of showing me 7,12, 120003, it just showed me 1,2,3. Why does that happend?
Initial dataframe:
[image]
Here's my code:

```
ads_df = pd.read_csv('clicks.csv')
each_ad_counts= ads_df.groupby('ad_id').size()
each_ad_click_counts= ads_df.groupby('ad_id')['clicked'].sum()
```

After groupby:

[image]

But in the original dataframe, there is not ad_id as 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (Also, there is a convention on stack overflow to not include greetings such as "Thanks!')

Comment: Just edited my question

Comment: Try adding `.reset_index()` to the end of your second line. Does this help?

Comment: Anyone wanting to help would probably need at least sample data to try and replicate your problem.

Comment: Pictures aren't great, we need something we can use (either something we can read through `pd.read_clipboard` or a sample of code that produces a dataframe). Please read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Does the following work for you?
`df = pd.DataFrame({'ad_id': [7,12,120003,7,35,35,35,35,7], 'clicked':[0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]})`
`each_ad_click_counts = df.groupby('ad_id')['clicked'].sum()`
This yields the appropriate result for me with the correct ids.